# Please help identify set with 2x3 and 3x4 red slopes with blue and yellow triangle printing?

Tags: part-identification

[image]

Any help identifying the set these bricks come from would be appreciated.  They possibly look like awnings maybe to a town storefront.

Answer (score 3):

Part [3297px18 - Slope 33 3 x 4 with Blue Triangles with Yellow Borders Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3297px18&name=Slope%2033%203%20x%204%20with%20Blue%20Triangles%20with%20Yellow%20Borders%20Pattern&category=%5BSlope,%20Decorated%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) appears in [5 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3297px18&in=S).

Assuming for a moment that all 4 of these bricks come from the same set, there are two possible sets that you could have (there is [one more set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4271-1) that has 1 of the 3x4 and two of the 3x2 slopes).

1. [4226 Building Monsters](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4226-1) - contains 4 of each.

[image: https://www.bricklink.com/SL/4226-1.jpg?0]

2. [9287 Bonus Lego Basic Town](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9287-1) - contains 12 of each.

[image]